# CSS3 toggle icon

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Please find the code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/mxmt90Yb894ZzDQ7iP9S?p=preview)

I toggle a class `min` upon button click. To show this the color is toggled. Is there a way to add an icon to the button, which toggles for example between: `icon-double-angle-right` and  `icon-double-angle-left`. I linked [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) CDN. I only care about recent browser, so mainly looking for pseudo elements based sol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with pseudo attributes :

CSS :

```
btn.min { background:red; }
.btn:after {
  content: attr(data-active-icon);
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
.btn.min:after {
  content: attr(data-inactive-icon);
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
}
```

HTML :

```
<button class="btn" ng-class="{min: min}" ng-click="toggle()" data-active-icon='&#xf104;' data-inactive-icon='&#xf105;'></button>
```

Where your `data-active-icon` and `data-inactive-icon` is taken from [this table](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/design.html).

Demo : http://jsbin.com/ariwij/1/edit

I haven't included bootstrap in the demo, but it will integrate just fine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you didn't save your demo... ahahahahah :D

Comment: Haha poor me, let me check it out if its in the browser

Comment: @AndreaLigios, safely tabbed 1 hour ago... 10x for your comment.

Comment: I would be happy with the missing 1x :D

Answer (score 0):

Make your HTML like this: `<button class="btn" ng-class="{min: min}" ng-click="toggle()"><span class="arrow-left"></span></button>`

Then use javascript or jquery to replace the class on the `<span>` with a different class on toggle.  Then make your two CSS class rules, one with background image for your left facing arrow, one for your right facing arrow, or whatever the stylistic thing it is you want to achieve.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite click the code the OP linked to above and you will see.

Answer (score 0):

consider that your button is #butt:

```
$("#butt").click(function(){
     $(this).toggle('red');
})
```

and CSS:

```
.red{
 color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To toggle an icon via class, have a look here:
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_toggle_like_dislike